# Electron openItem opens new window of same path

Tags: windows, shell, electron

I'm using Electron. When I fire `shell.openItem(fullPath to folderA)` on button click it opens folder A in widow (correct). 
But If I fire `shell.openItem(fullPath to folderA)` again from different button. Instead of bringing already opened folder, it opening folder Ain new window.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is actually an observation. Yes, `openItem` works that way. (deep inside it calls [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) with "explore" verb option, which works this way)

If you want consecutive calls to use the same window you can use `openExternal` (which deep inside executes shell with "open" option, which works this way). It will keep the same window open until you don't navigate away

*Tested with `6.0.1`*

```
const { shell } = require('electron')

setInterval(() => {
  shell.openExternal(__dirname)
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Since Electron 9.0 the `shell.openItem()` has been replaced by `shell.openPath()`